Dynamic Pivot Columns List PL/SQL
I am currently trying to craft a pivot statement with a dynamic list of pivot columns, and here is the code I have so far.  It is currently the source code for an interactive report.


DECLARE
    pivot_col_list varchar2(4000); //created using a listagg query with a static value in its where clause
    PI_pivot_col_list varchar2(4000); //created using a listagg query with a page item in its where clause
    LOOP_pivot_col_list varchar2(4000); //created using a loop
    executeImmediate_pivot_col_list varchar2(4000); //created with an execute immediate statement
    execute_query varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
    SELECT listagg('''' || NAME || ''' "' || NAME || '"', ',') INTO pivot_col_list FROM FRA4_PARTS WHERE TEMPLATE_ID = 1;
    SELECT listagg('''' || NAME || ''' "' || NAME || '"', ',') INTO PI_pivot_col_list FROM FRA4_PARTS WHERE TEMPLATE_ID = :P56_TEMPLATE_ID;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT listagg('''''''' || NAME || '''''' "'' || NAME || ''"'', '','') FROM FRA4_PARTS WHERE TEMPLATE_ID = ' || templateID INTO executeImmediate_pivot_col_list;
    FOR c1 IN (SELECT '''' || NAME || ''' "' || NAME || '"' AS pivot_col FROM FRA4_PARTS WHERE TEMPLATE_ID = :P56_TEMPLATE_ID) LOOP
        LOOP_pivot_col_list := LOOP_pivot_col_list || c1.pivot_col || ',';
    END LOOP;
    LOOP_pivot_col_list := SUBSTR(LOOP_pivot_col_list, 1, LENGTH(LOOP_pivot_col_list) - 1);
    
    apex_debug.info('Static:    ' || pivot_col_list);
    apex_debug.info('Page Item: ' || PI_pivot_col_list);
    
    execute_query := 
    'SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT 
            response.ID AS RESPONSE_ID,
            criteria.NAME AS CRITERIA_NAME,
            criteria.ID AS CRITERIA_ID,
            part.NAME AS PART_NAME,
            options.RESPONSE AS RESPONSE_NAME,
            criteria.GATE_REVIEW AS GATE_REVIEW
        FROM (
            SELECT
                ID,
                PART_ID,
                CRITERIA_ID,
                TEMPLATE_ID,
                RESPONSE_OPTION_ID,
                GATE_REVIEW
            FROM FRA4_RESPONSES WHERE TEMPLATE_ID = :P56_TEMPLATE_ID
        ) response
        LEFT JOIN FRA4_PARTS part ON response.PART_ID = part.ID
        FULL JOIN FRA4_CRITERIA criteria ON response.CRITERIA_ID = criteria.ID
        LEFT JOIN FRA4_RESPONSE_OPTIONS options ON response.RESPONSE_OPTION_ID = options.ID
        LEFT JOIN FRA4_TEMPLATES template ON response.TEMPLATE_ID = template.GATE_REVIEW
    ) 
    pivot (
        Min(RESPONSE_NAME) for PART_NAME in (
            ' || LOOP_pivot_col_list || '
        )
    ) WHERE GATE_REVIEW = :P56_GATE_REVIEW ORDER BY CRITERIA_ID ASC';

    apex_debug.info(execute_query);
    return execute_query;
END;



The issue I'm having is I won't have any pivot columns show up in my query if I use PI_pivot_col_list or LOOP_pivot_col_list as the field for the pivot columns but if I use pivot_col_list or replate the page item with the value that the page item holds then I see the pivot columns.
I can ensure that both PI_pivot_col_list and pivot_col_list contain the same values within the debugger and that the page item I am trying to access is being submitted to the report region that this code is from.
I also have made sure that the page item is submitted to the report that the query is trying to use.

UPDATE:
I have made a bit of progress with my bug testing and I think I may have found a cause of the issue but still don't know how to fix it.
What seems to be happening is whenever I validate the source query with a change the list of columns within the region tree in the right side panel (sorry for not knowing the term for that area) seems to change and whenever the source code runs it looks for that specific list of columns at run time regardless of what the list actually is.

UPDATE Pt 2:
I believe I have recreated the issue using sample data I think the main issue is that I'm changing the amount of columns each time and report regions don't like that.  The source query is this:


DECLARE
    pivot_cols varchar2(4000);
    return_query varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
    SELECT listagg('''' || DEPTNO || ''' "' || DNAME || '"', ',') INTO pivot_cols FROM DEPT WHERE DEPTNO < :P56_DEPT;
    
    return_query :=
    'SELECT * FROM EBA_DEMO_DIALOG_EMP
    pivot (
        count(ENAME) FOR DEPTNO IN (
            ' || pivot_cols || '
        )
    )';

    return return_query;
END;



Where :P56_DEPT is a select list page item who's source query is:


SELECT
    DNAME,
    DEPTNO
FROM DEPT



The same error occurs, where if I enter the value 30 in lue of :P56_DEPT the code works just fine but if the value of :P56_DEPT is 30 none of the pivot columns appear.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Do you have P56_TEMPLATE_ID in "items to submit" for your report ?

Yes I do have that page item submitted

Kinda hard to say what is wrong since this is on your own data and datastructure. If you're able to reproduce this on the emp/dept sample dataset I'm happy to give it a try.

Sure thing, I added some edits above

Yeah that is most probably the issue. The IR region needs to know the number of columns  and its names beforehand. In a classic report you can use the "generic column names" attribute and use page items to determine the column names on the fly that could be a solution. In that case nr of columns can vary too.

Good to know, is it possible to convert this query to a csv easily even if I cannot get the view?

I don't see why not. Use APEX_DATA_EXPORT instead of a report

Just got it working, greatly appreciate your help!

Good to know you got it to work. Best way to say thanks here is to mark the question as answered - that gives the member reputation points. In this case I didn't answer (only commented) so it's not relevant but several of your other questions had a proper answer but never got marked as answered - so you know what to do ;)
